# How to set portfast default on Dell FTOS Switches?

Tags: spanning-tree, dell, force10

I'm configuring a Dell S3148 switch running FTOS 9.14.0.1 and I would like to achieve similar functionality of the following Cisco IOS commands:

```
spanning-tree portfast default
spanning-tree portfast bpduguard default
spanning-tree portfast bpdufilter default
spanning-tree loopguard default
```

I wasn't able to find the equivalent settings on the manual and I don't want to make this on a port by port basis.

There's a way to enable this features on this device?